# I am trying to design an LL(1) Parser that accepts T = {a, b *, +, ?, E, U, (, ) }

Tags: formal-languages, formal-grammars, parsers, left-recursion

I am trying to design an LL(1) Parser that accepts regular notation where 'E' represents epsilon, and 'U' represents "or" like ' | '.

So far I made one that accepts T = { a, b, *, +, (, ), E}

```
S -> T S'
S' -> + S | ε

T -> F T'
T' -> T | ε

F -> P F'
F' -> * F' | ε

P -> ( S ) | c | E

c -> D M
M -> C | ε
D -> a | b
```

I am having trouble on what production I should add so that it will accept 'U' and ?. so it will allow something like these:

```
(a* U b+)* U a U E

E
```

but hopefully won't allow these:

```
(a*)* 

(a*)+ 

(a*)? - doesn't need optional because a* is already Zero or More

(a+)? - since this is basically a*

abE
```

I'll be really grateful for any kind of help I can get :D

Comment: The grammar you copied decribes arithmetic expressions which use the addition and multiplication operators. But the expressions you are trying to parse are not arithmetic. While they happen to also use the same symbols, `+` and `*`, they use them in a completely different way. It is not so important that the meaning comes from a different problem domain. For the purposes of parsing, what matters is that the symbols have different syntactic roles. In arithmetic, they are infix operators  with two operands. But in your context, they are postfix operators with a single operand.

Comment: So the arithmetic grammar you copied isn't going to of much direct use, although it could help you describe the $\cup$ operator, which is an infix operator. If you turn your eyes sideways, it might also help you model the "invisible" concatenation operator. But mostly, it's main practical value is as an example of how to translate a particular syntax into a grammar, a task which involves some understanding of what grammars mean.

Comment: sorry I forgot to add the production that can use a or b multiple times.. I havev edited it ..

Comment: You give some negative examples that should not belong to the language. However, these are valid regular expressions. Can you explain what your language consists of? Otherwise, it would be impossible to answer it.